# send is calling the wrong class because of a scope with reserved word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model and I'm doing a simple status filter from params:

```
result.send(params[:status])
```

However one of the statuses is `open`, which seems to be a reserved word. Unfortunately, I can't change this status name...

Is there any alternative for the following issue:

ATM `send` is calling a method from `open-uri` and not from the `User` model.

```
result.class #=> User::ActiveRecord_Relation
result.send("open")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+)
    from /Users/gabrielhilal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:29:in `open'
result.open #=> works fine
```

The scope is defined by [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) gem, and the `result` has some `where` conditions:

```
def self.search(params)
  query = "%#{params[:query]}%"
  result = where(
    "lower(first_name || ' ' || last_name) like lower(:query)",
    :query => query
  )
  result = result.send(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
end
```

Comment: What does the whole scope look like?

Comment: That is not a `model` that is a collection of `models`. `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Even if that `collection` only contains 1 element. Since `ActiveRecord::Relation` does not define `open` it bubbles up the hierarchy stack looking for `open` and lands at `Kernel#open` eg. `ActiveRecord::Relation.method(:open) #=> #<Method: Class(Kernel)#open>` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-open

Comment: @jvillian I've edited the question to include it

Comment: I poked around the gem a little. Do you happen to know where `self.search` is defined? I'm a bit surprised by the `first_name`, `last_name` stuff b/c that doesn't seem very state machine-y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated

`#public_send` will work. `Kernel#open` is a private method so it won't land there and will get picked up by `ActiveRecord::Relation#method_missing` like it's supposed to.

Comment: yeah, I think `public_send` works because the Kernel `open` is private, so it will use the `open` scope provided by the gem instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`open` is a method of `Kernel` class. Check [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-open).

```
method( :open ).owner
=> Kernel
```

You can't use `open` with `send`, like you're doing now. Probably you can alias `open`method in model.

You can add a `before_filter` callback in controller to replace `open` with some other name and define that name as an alias method of `open` in model.